# Term double prompting (duplicate prompts) in Emacs

Tags: shell, ansi-term, term, prompt

My **term** in emacs appear:

```
0;me@debian: ~me@debian:~$
```

instead of `me@debian:~$`

```
~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;33m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[0;35m\]$\[\033[0m\]
```

Versions:

**debian-9.5.0** and **GNU Emacs 25.1.1**

I tried various solutions given in stackexchange by adding additional lines to `.bashrc` and `init.el`

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812345/emacs-terminal-bash-ps1-prompt-duplicated
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579662/shell-prompt-repeating-when-using-ssh-in-ansi-term

But nothing worked out. This issue is there in **shell** also; but not in **eshell**.

Comment: Show us what you tried.  What were these "various solutions" which didn't work?  Also, what does `echo $PS1` report in the shell?  Does the problem persist if you type `export PS1="\u@\h:\w$ "` at the shell prompt?

Comment: Phils: Thanks for response. I edited the question.

Comment: Phils: I tried your advice: (1) No syntax highlight or bold text (2) And it last for that terminal session only.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be seeing *exactly* what your `PS1` says to display.  At minimum, you have `\u@\h` in there twice.  Why is that?

Comment: Reducing that to just `PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;33m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[0;35m\]$\[\033[0m\] "` (eliminating the duplicate at the start) seems to work in both `term` and my stand-alone terminal (at least in cursory tests).

Comment: Ok, so those links you've added are clearly duplicates.  If you've still ended up with the xterm-specific escape codes in your PS1 value, then something has gone awry with the code you added to prevent that -- but we don't know what that looks like in your config, so show us the code you ended up with for setting PS1, when you tried to follow those solutions.

Comment: Thanks Phils: The PS1 script you gave works fine in all the terminals, when I added it to .basrc. So, request you to please add your answer formally. Then , I will approve it. Thanks again for your efforts, time, and sincerity. Hats off to you !!!

Comment: You're welcome. Answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the S.O. duplicates linked to in the question, the initial `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]` is intended to set the title text of an xterm window.  If the terminal does not recognise those (non-standard) escape codes (as is the case in `term` and `shell`), you end up with the situation shown in the question.

If you want to retain the xterm behaviour in compatible terminals, you should perform the appropriate tests in your shell config when setting `PS1`, such that you only set that prefix in situations where it is supported.

If you don't care about xterm window titles, then just remove the prefix from the prompt entirely.  If you want to keep those, then add those codes conditionally.

```sh
# Generic colour prompt (works in Emacs)
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;33m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[0;35m\]$\[\033[0m\] "

# In an xterm, also set the window title
case $TERM in
    xterm*) PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1";;
esac
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Phils, thank you for your time, effort, and sincere approach. Hats off to you !!!

Comment: Is there a way to get the terminal title also back? In fact, i did not notice that it was missing...

Comment: I can only suggest the general approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17598138 whereby you would conditionally set `PS1` to have those additional escape sequences only if the value of `TERM` matched `xterm*`.  You don't need to define a function, though -- I would just put the `case` block directly in your config file (and of course substitute your own title and prompt for the ones they've used).

Comment: n.b. If that doesn't do the trick, you may have some other terminal which also supports those escape codes, and hence might need to test for additional `TERM` patterns.  If it's all a mystery, let me know what `echo $TERM` says.

Comment: xterm-256color
My Xfce terminal and eshell works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, well `xterm*` will certainly match that.  I've updated the answer with a simpler version of what the other Q&A shows.  I can't properly test it as my window manager doesn't show window titles, but hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and found it was caused (in fish at least), by `fish_title` being set.

This resolved the issue:

```fish
if status is-interactive
    if [ "$TERM" = "eterm-color" ]
        # pass
    else
        function fish_title
            if [ $_ = 'fish' ]
                echo "["(prompt_pwd)"]"
            else
                echo "("$_")"
            end
        end
    end
end
```